How should I prepare this shower curb gap for silicone caulk?
The grout in the shower curb has cracked and fallen out over the years.
I plan to fill it with 100% silicone sealant but am unsure of how to clean/prep the area first.
The gap goes 1/4" - 5/8" deep and is filled with brown substance I believe is thinset mortar plus some old hairs and dirt/residue.
My idea was to use some alcohol and a toothbrush plus towels to clean up any hairs/oil and leave the thinset as much as possible. I could also just use a plastic putty knife to scrape everything out but am worried that may affect the tile adhesion or I may cut through the shower liner.
Any ideas on how much/how deep I should clean before caulking? I want to prep the area as best as possible for the silicone without disrupting anything, but am unfamiliar with the anatomy of the shower curb and tiling.

For single tile you can do it manually.
For multiple tile grouts use a tile grout cleaner tool.
grout

Will probably do it manually since there's only a handful of tiles. Do you have any idea how thorough I can be? I'm thinking to only clean the surface of the brown layer without removing it.

@Saryupop12 it has to be clean enough so new will stick to it
